# Signing Soap header by passing the whole X509 certificate chain using C#

Tags: c#, soap, .net-framework-version, x509certificate2

All,
I am trying to digitally sign a SOAP request header as part of calling a java api.
I am using C# with .Net framework 4.5. I manually created the soap request and when I send the signed request after signing with my X509Certificate's private key (.pfx cert file), the Mulesoft orchestration layer that Java service uses is complaining that my  value doesn't contain the whole certificate chain. I use C#'s X509Certificate class's GetRawCertData() and converting this byte[] to base64 encoded string. I can see the intermediate and root certificate when I view this .pfx in my personal certificate store using mmc. This .pfx certificate was given to me by our org's server admin. Does anyone know any other way to pass the whole certificate chain in the **wsse:BinarySecurityToken** element using C#? Please see my sample soap envelope below.

I am using HttpClient and Web Api ( .Net framework) to send this request to Java service)

C# logic to set the value of the wsse:BinarySecurityToken element

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = GetCertificateBySubjectName();
byte[] rawData = x509Certificate.GetRawCertData();    
var cerrtBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(rawData);
binarySecurityToken.InnerText = cerrtBase64String ;

public  X509Certificate2 GetCertificateBySubjectName(string subjectName)
        {

            // Load the certificate from the certificate store.
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;

            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            try
            {
                // Open the store.
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                // Find the certificate with the specified subject.
                cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectName, false)[0];

                // Throw an exception of the certificate was not found.
                if (cert == null)
                {
                    throw new CryptographicException("The certificate could not be found.");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var message = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the store even if an exception was thrown.
                store.Close();
            }

            return cert;
        }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <wsse:Security xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
 <wsse:BinarySecurityToken  
               EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
               ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509" 
               wsu:Id="x509cert00">MIIChDCCAe2gAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEMMAoGA1UEChMD
                                   SUJNMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpXaWxsIFlhdGVzMB4XDTA2MDEzMTAwMDAwMFoXDTA3MDEzMTIzNTk1OVow
                                   MDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxDDAKBgNVBAoTA0lCTTETMBEGA1UEAxMKV2lsbCBZYXRlczCBnzANBgkq
                                   hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEArsRj/n+3RN75+jaxuOMBWSHvZCB0egv8qu2UwLWEeiogePsR
                                   6Ku4SuHbBwJtWNr0xBTAAS9lEa70yhVdppxOnJBOCiERg7S0HUdP7a8JXPFzA+BqV63JqRgJyxN6
                                   msfTAvEMR07LIXmZAte62nwcFrvCKNPCFIJ5mkaJ9v1p7jkCAwEAAaOBrTCBqjA/BglghkgBhvhC
                                   AQ0EMhMwR2VuZXJhdGVkIGJ5IHRoZSBTZWN1cml0eSBTZXJ2ZXIgZm9yIHovT1MgKFJBQ0YpMDgG
                                   ZQVRFU0BVSy5JQk0uQ09ggdJQk0uQ09NhgtXV1cuSUJNLkNPTYcECRRlBjAO
 </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
 <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                 xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
   <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <c14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds wsu xenc SOAP-ENV "/>
   </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <ds:Reference URI="#TheBody">
    <ds:Transforms>
     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
       <c14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsu SOAP-ENV "/>
     </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/> 
    <ds:DigestValue>QORZEA+gpafluShspHxhrjaFlXE=</ds:DigestValue> 
   </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>drDH0XESiyN6YJm27mfK1ZMG4Q4IsZqQ9N9V6kEnw2lk7aM3if77XNFnyKS4deglbC3ga11kkaFJ
                     p4jLOmYRqqycDPpqPm+UEu7mzfHRQGe7H0EnFqZpikNqZK5FF6fvYlv2JgTDPwrOSYXmhzwegUDT
                     lTVjOvuUgXYrFyaO3pw=</ds:SignatureValue>
   <ds:KeyInfo>
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:Reference URI="#x509cert00" 
                      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
 </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TheBody">
 <getVersion xmlns="http://msgsec.wssecfvt.ws.ibm.com"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: A certificate is a string.  You can open up the certificate and notepad and see the data.  Converting to byte[] and then using Convert.ToBase64String() will modify the string.  After reading the certificate the key should look the same as in notepad.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for chiming in. I opened up the .cer file ( Public one) that we gave to the client and compared the base64 string with what I get when using Convert.ToBase64(cert.GetRawData()) and see they are similar. I will check with them to see they are using the correct .cer file for validation. I can't open the .pfx though, all I see is bunch of unprintable ascii codes

Comment: They must look exactly alike. At least the key portion.  PFX file is encrypted and you need to use  a key to decrypt.  It contains the private key.

Answer (score 0):

`GetRawCertData()` returns the bytes that make up the certificate, ignoring any "attached data" like the private key or friendly name or whatnot.  It's not a tie-back to the file that it was loaded from or anything magical.

> the whole certificate chain

You don't show how you loaded the PFX, but the most common way is the X509Certificate2 constructor (`new X509Certificate2(pfx, pwd, maybeSomeFlags)`).  Since that's a single certificate's constructor it can only load one certificate.  The other way is to import it into a collection

```
X509Certificate2Collection coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
coll.Import(pfx, pwd, maybeSomeFlags);
```

from there you'd presumably loop whatever you did to add `x509cert00` for all the elements in that collection.  Of course, that's assuming that the collection is sorted the way you like and has no extraneous data.  If you want to know that it's sorted into a proper chain you'd have to run the signing certificate through `X509Chain.Build` (after copying the rest of the collection into `chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore`).

Comment: thanks for  helping me.  Added the logic to load the certificate by subject name. Are you saying that GetRawCertData() already contains all the certificates in the certificate chain?

Comment: @RennishJoseph No, it only contains the data for the one certificate it's invoked on.  If you're fetching your certificate out of a cert store, then the only way to know what the other certs are is to use X509Chain.

Comment: thanks, this helps and I will do more research to see how can  pass the whole cert chain. This is a good starting point